# Login failed for user ' ' when the login worked before

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms, connection-string

I can't access the database with my login through visual studio. I can login and access the database with MSQL Server MS though (Authentication - SQL server authentication).

This was not a problem before I synced together with a few other projects, but I can't find where I am going wrong, maybe I am missing a connection or something. I got the `Login failed for user ' '` error at `Database.Initialize(true);`.

My connection string in web.config is as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Hololens" connectionString="Server=tcp:adress.net,1433;
         Initial Catalog=HololensDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=HololensUser;Password=hololens;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;
         TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this? Or why this error is occurring now but not before?

Comment: Perhaps you have some kind of transform on your web.config that is removing the login. Clearly it's using a different login to the one you posted in the string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid but how can that be really, because as I said, I can login with the same userId and password when connecting to the database through ssms O.o

Comment: Your error says you are logging in with a blank username

Comment: oh, no I just left it blank to make it more general. My userId is in the error as well @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: There is a sql profiler in the tools menu of Sql mgmt studio. It will show you the login request where you can see the username. Check if it is using same details or some other login info.

Comment: If you want more info on the login failure, look in the SQL Server logs and you'll get more detail on the issue. I'm guessing it's going to say incorrect password.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid how can it be the wrong password if I can login with the same password and username in sql mgmt studio?

Comment: @MatJ I don't have the authority in SQL server profiler yet. I'll be back with an answer next week :)

Comment: None of it makes sense so check the sql server log and find some information that will shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every possible solution we could think of, I finally decided to delete the database in SSMS and run the contextInitializer again. This actually worked, there was no longer an `Login failed for user`-error.

Without looking into this matter further I figured that maybe my user was not allowed to drop or create the database or something - this because the initializer has `DropOrCreateIfModelChanges`.

Still this was not explained in the login failure error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looking in the SQL Server log would have given you more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it solves the issue, but I think the connection string should not contain any line breaks.

Please keep the entire connectionString attribute value in a single line and try again.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Hololens"
         connectionString="Server=tcp:adress.net,1433;Initial Catalog=HololensDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=HololensUser;Password=hololens;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Do you mean no `;` ?

Comment: Do you mean not separating the connection sting on several rows? the string will work on several or one row the same, just makes it easier to read. tried it though and I still got the same error.

Comment: In the past, I have seen quite a few code examples on Internet with remarks that the used connection string values should not be split on multiple lines, but should be kept on a single line (without line breaks). I have not tried it, however, so you may be right. It's worth giving a try, though...

Comment: Np! I juts want it to work again so I'll try anything :)